# Code decreases value of number if next to a 0 in an array. When i place a 0 in the first place in the array the program doesn't work

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

Attempting to decrease the value of a number in an array if next to a certain value.

I’m trying to fix an error in my code where it won’t properly decrease numbers in my array if they are next to the number zero and zero is in the first or last position. I want my code to output this:

```
Day 0: {0,6,7,9,3,5,6,1} 
Day 1: {0,3,7,9,3,5,6,1} 
Day 2: {0,1,7,9,3,5,6,1} 
Day 3: {0,0,7,9,3,5,6,1} 
Day 4: {0,0,3,9,3,5,6,1}    
Day 5: {0,0,1,9,3,5,6,1} 
Day 6: {0,0,0,4,3,5,6,1} 
Day 7: {0,0,0,2,3,5,6,1} 
Day 8: {0,0,0,1,3,5,6,1} 
Day 9: {0,0,0,0,1,5,6,1}   
Day 10: {0,0,0,0,0,5,6,1} 
Day 11: {0,0,0,0,0,2,6,1} 
Day 12: {0,0,0,0,0,1,6,1} 
Day 13: {0,0,0,0,0,0,6,1} 
Day 14: {0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1}    
Day 15: {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1} 
Day 16: {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1} 
Day 17: {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1} 
Day 18: {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}    
---extinct---
```

However it outputs this instead:

```
Day 295279: 0, 0, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6, 1.
Day 295280: 0, 0, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6, 1.
Day 295281: 0, 0, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6, 1.
Day 295282: 0, 0, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6, 1.
Day 295283: 0, 0, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6, 1.
Day 295284: 0, 0, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6, 1.
Day 295285: 0, 0, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6, 1.
```

It keeps on repeating to infinity. My code is the following:

```
public class Final {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 int[] settlement = {3,6,7,0,3,5,6,1};

 int daycont=0;
 System.out.println("Day 0: "+settlement[0]+", "+settlement[1]+", "+settlement[2]+", "+settlement[3]+", "+settlement[4]+", "+settlement[5]+", "+settlement[6]+", "+settlement[7]+".");
 while(settlement[0]!=0 || settlement[1]!=0 ||settlement[2]!=0 || settlement[3]!=0 || settlement[4]!=0 || settlement[5]!=0 || settlement[6]!=0 || settlement[7]!=0) { 
  daycont++;
 for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
  if (settlement[i]==0) {
   if(i!=7){
   i++;
   settlement[i]= settlement[i]/2;}
   if(i!=1 && i!=0)
   i=i-2;
   settlement[i]= settlement[i]/2;
   i++;
  }
 }

 System.out.println("Day "+daycont+": "+settlement[0]+", "+settlement[1]+", "+settlement[2]+", "+settlement[3]+", "+settlement[4]+", "+settlement[5]+", "+settlement[6]+", "+settlement[7]+".");
 }

for (int extcounter=0; extcounter<8; extcounter++) {
 if (settlement[extcounter]==0) {
  extcounter++;
  if (extcounter==8)
   System.out.println("----EXTINCT----");

 }

}}
}
```

Can someone explain why it’s not working properly? I’m stumped I tried googling and browsing stack overflow but, I couldn’t find anything. (Note I’m using a one dimensional array and I’ve only recently started Java so I have a very basic understanding and some of the code I’ve seen on Stack Overflow I don’t really understand) Thank you in advance. :D

Comment: I have not idea what your title means. Can you please explain with some samples

Comment: Sure, my code is suppose to look at the number's in the array and decrease them by half if they are next to 0 in the array. My code should output (this is just an example, Day 0: 5, 6 ,0, 4 then Day 1: 5,3,0,2. and continue doing so until no numbers are greater than zero in the array. However when I have a 0 as the first number in the array my code outputs something like this, Day 0: 0, 2, 6 , 4 then Day 1: 0, 1. 6 , 4 then Day 2: 0, 0 , 6, 4 then Day 3: 0, 0 , 6 ,4. It only decreases then number next to it then stops. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I have run your code and it just seems to be in an endless loop. Have you tried debugging your code? I have got no idea how your explanation relates to your code.

Comment: I've tried to figure it out. I'll try looking at it again. I'll see if I can work out what's wrong and the go from there. I wasn't able to figure out after an hour but maybe something will come to me. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: As I said, try debugging it - try some [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: Instead of doing `i++` and then setting `settlement[i]`, just do `settlement[i+1] = settlement[i+1] / 2`, likewise you can also do `setlement[i-1] = settlement[i-1] / 2`